# Changing the mouse position in GLUT?

Tags: objective-c, macos, mouse, glut

I'm trying to rotate the camera with the mouse. Moving it isn't a problem, but I need to keep it into one place. I've tried glutWarpPointer() but it slows down the program SIGNIFICANTLY. I'm trying to write an engine for something and don't want to use and add ons.

```
int diff = x - oldx;
oldx = x; rx += diff;
if (rx > 360) 
    rx = 0; 

if (rx < 0) 
    rx = 360; 

NSLog(@"%f",rx);
back = YES; 
glutWarpPointer(0, 0); 
glutPostRedisplay();
```

Comment: int diff = x - oldx;
    oldx =  x;
    rx += diff;
    if (rx > 360)
        rx = 0;
    
    if (rx < 0)
        rx = 360;
    NSLog(@"%f",rx);
    back = YES;
    glutWarpPointer(0, 0);
    glutPostRedisplay();

Answer (score 0):

`glutWarpPointer` should be pretty fast on OS X; where are you calling it in your program?

It can sometimes force `glutPassiveMotionFunc` to be invoked as well, so watch out for that.

Comment: I was calling it in the passive motion, which didn't work then I tried it in the draw function. Would it help you make it its own function?

Answer (score 0):

It requires stepping out of GLUT, but you can use `CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(false);` to make it so that mouse movements don't move the cursor (neither the visual cursor nor the absolute position reported in events, etc.).  Subsequent mouse events have an unchanging absolute position but include appropriate deltas to provide the movement.  I don't know if those deltas are accessible from GLUT.

Comment: I fixed my problem but forgot to answer the question. I used CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval and it worked fine. Thanks for the help though :D